# How can I deploy a 503 maintenance page when upgrading a Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: nginx, maintenance, 503-error

Usually when I perform maintenance that requires briefly taking my site down, I put up a 503 page using something similar to [How can I make Nginx return HTTP 503 when my proxied app server is down?](https://serverfault.com/questions/186632/how-can-i-make-nginx-return-http-503-when-my-proxied-app-server-is-down).

However, I'm about to upgrade my Digital Ocean droplet to a larger size, so the 503 error won't get sent. One way I could achieve this is to put my 503 error page on a separate droplet and redirect my DNS to this other IP address while I upgrade the droplet. However, I'm afraid this might raise flags with Google if they crawl my site then.

How should I go about notifying users and bots that I'm performing maintenance when I have to take down my entire server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google really doesn't care that your IP address flops around a little.  Just change the DNS (with an appropriately low TTL set well in advance to ensure your visitors with cached DNS don't go to the machine under maintenance).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `floating IP` functionality to temporarily redirect your traffic to a different droplet?